# how to set columns to get automatically without giving directly in code in php for excel sheet

Tags: php, mysql, excel

How to set cell/column value dynamically using PHPExcel library?

I am fetching result set from MySQL database and I want to write data in excel format using PHPExcel library. Looking at example

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'cell value here');
indicates that we have to hard code cell/column reference As 'A1', then it writes to cell/column A1. How I can increment cell/column and/or row reference based on rows and corresponding column values from result set?

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Function that will help you is called `setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col_number, $row_number, value)`. - `$col_number` is integer (A-0, B-1, C-2 ,...).

So you can set start values for example:

```
$col = 0
$row = 1
```

And you can change them in loops when you iterate through your data for example:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value); // set A1 value
$col++ // (move to next column) ;
```

or

```
$row++ // move to next row
```

and move to next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

'A1' is simply a PHP string, so you can use a variable or a concatenation of variables.... I'm afraid that the developers of PHPExcel made the assumption that users would understand this, which might explain why they failed to bother documenting it.

```
for ($row = 1; $row <= 10; ++$row) {
    for ($column = 'A'; $column != 'K'; ++$column) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(
            $column . $row, 
            "Row {$row}, Column {$column}"
        );
    }
}
```